# JSF FacesMessage localization

Tags: jsf, localization

My problem now is that I can't get localization working with FacesMessage

I've tried:

```
try {
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("translations", context.getViewRoot().getLocale());
    text = bundle.getString("loginFail");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e);
}

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", new FacesMessage(text));
```

but the following exception is thrown

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name translations, locale cs
```

**faces-config.xml** contains:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>cs</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>tr.translations</base-name>
        <var>txt</var>
    </resource-bundle>
    <message-bundle>
        tr.translations
    </message-bundle>
</application>
```

Files **translations_cs.properties** and **translations_en.properties** are in the tr package, the location is definitely ok.

Do you have any idea how to get it working? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basename in `getBundle()` should be `tr.translations`, exactly as you have in `faces-config.xml`.